# Preventing Duplicate Records to save in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce-id

I have created a lightning component that accepts input from user and saves the data to the custom object.
Now i want to check duplication of the record based on two fields. Let suppose Name and Date, i.e if name and date together of the current record is same as any other existing record then it should not be saved.

How do i handle that in apex?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share your lightning component you have mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Use the platform's configurable built-in [duplicate rules mechanism](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management/sales_admin_duplicate_management_unit_2) and report any errors this generates back to the user in your component.